# Add on numbers in a table

Tags: php

Say i have a database with a table which i have numbers on. Is there some way that i can add 1 number digit onto another one. for example i query what the fist number is and then add 1 number on to that. like if it was 1 and i clicked a button it will make it 2. How would this be possible? At the moment i just add a 1 into a new row every time but i need it to be classified under names. and it is really easy the way i have it now. if you don't understand don't hesitate to comment.

mine. it adds up all the ones

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

what i need to accomplish.

```
joe frank 1
```

and when i click the link

```
joe frank 2
```

Does that make sense

Comment: You are storing the current number on database. Then you can use the update statement: update <table> set <column> = <column> + 1 where <userid> = <some id> . Is this what you want?

Comment: i have a row in the database and i need to add 1 number on top of the last number that was there. everytime a button is clicked @vishwakarma09

Comment: show your html contents also that will helpful

Comment: its basicly useles @SanoojT

Comment: So What you need is when user clicks a button you need to update number in database and show that with name?

Comment: i just need whatever number in that database to increase in 1 decimel.@SanoojT

Comment: update <table> set <column> = <column> + 1 where <userid> = <some id>  why this don't work?

Comment: were would i put that @SanoojT

Comment: well my friend last and final question give your table structure which has the column name sorry for the late reply.